# Integration of Javascript and PHP functions and Validation

Tags: php, javascript, forms, function, xhtml

I had an assignment where I needed to call a validation `onsubmit` in JavaScript. This part worked beautifully.

The second part was to incorporate PHP validation for the server side. The coding is supposedly to be in the same page, therefore what I have below is through some research and examples I found and this is what I came up with:

```
<?php
echo "<form action='' method='post' onsubmit='return regValidation()' id='RegistrationForm'>";
echo "  <div>";
echo "  <span class='reglbl'>";
echo "      First Name: <input type='text' name='FirstName' id='FirstNameID'/>";
echo "      Last Name: <input type='text' name='LastName' id='LastNameID'/>";
echo "  </span>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div>";
echo "  <span class='reglbl'>";
echo "      Email Address: <input type='text' name='email' id='EmailID'/>";
echo "      Phone Number: <input type='text' name='PhoneNum' id='PhoneNumID'/>";
echo "  </span>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='reglbl'>Pssword: <input type='password' name='PWD1' id='PWD1'/></div>";
echo "  <div class='reglbl'>Confirm Password: <input type='password' name='PWD2' id='PWD2'/></div>";
echo "  <div><input type='submit' value=' Register ' id='sub' /></div>";
echo "</form>";
if(!isset($_REQUEST['FirstName']) ||
    !isset($_REQUEST['LastName']) ||
    !isset($_REQUEST['email']) ||
    !isset($_REQUEST['PhoneNum']) ||
    !isset($_REQUEST['PWD1']) ||
    !isset($_REQUEST['PWD2']) ||
    $_REQUEST['FirstName'] =="" ||
    $_REQUEST['LastName'] == "" ||
    $_REQUEST['email'] == "" ||
    $_REQUEST['PhoneNum'] == "" ||
    $_REQUEST['PWD1'] == "" ||
    $_REQUEST['PWD2']=="") 
{
    echo "<script>alert('Please enter all fields!')</script>";
} elseif($_REQUEST['PWD1']!=$_REQUEST['PWD2']) {
    echo "<script>alert('Passwords entered do not match!')</script>";
} elseif(strlen($_REQUEST['PWD1'])<8||strlen($_REQUEST['PWD2'])<8) {
    echo "<script>alert('Passwords must be 8 or more characters!')</script>";
} else {
    // CALL A FUNCTION IN PHP HERE
}
?>
```

So both validation in Java and PHP are the same the only difference is that PHP checks a bit more for 8 character length for the passwords, but when this code is executed the JavaScript the only thing validating.

Also I would like to know how to call an external PHP that contains a script for the final else.

Here is the javascript code incase 
                    /REGISTAR VALIDATION
function regValidation(){

```
var firstName = document.getElementById('FirstNameID');
var lastName = document.getElementById('LastNameID');
var email = document.getElementById('EmailID');
var pwd1 = document.getElementById('PWD1');
var pwd2 = document.getElementById('PWD2');


if(firstName.value == '' || lastName.value == '' || email.value == '' || pwd1.value == '' || pwd2.value == '')
{
    alert("Please enter all fields!");
}
else if (pwd1.value !== pwd2.value)
{
    alert("Passwords entered do not match!");   
}
else
{

}
return false;
```

}

Comment: There is no client-side JavaScript validation in your code snippet.

Comment: I will kindly suggest you move the HTML part out of the PHP.

Comment: the javascript is externally called i just added the code of what my function does as well.

Comment: @JonasG.Drange what do you mean by that taking out the form section ??

Comment: I mean that echoing a bunch of HTML is bad practice.

Comment: okay i removed it, in my original code, also  i just noticed if i remove the onsubmit function for javascript the server side starts running so how can i fix this ???

Answer (score 0):

try this will help you

```
<?php
echo "<form action='' method='post' onsubmit='return regValidation()' id='RegistrationForm'>";
echo "  <div>";
echo "  <span class='reglbl'>";
echo "      First Name: <input type='text' name='FirstName' id='FirstNameID'/>";
echo "      Last Name: <input type='text' name='LastName' id='LastNameID'/>";
echo "  </span>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div>";
echo "  <span class='reglbl'>";
echo "      Email Address: <input type='text' name='email' id='EmailID'/>";
echo "      Phone Number: <input type='text' name='PhoneNum' id='PhoneNumID'/>";
echo "  </span>";
echo "  </div>";
echo "  <div class='reglbl'>Pssword: <input type='password' name='PWD1' id='PWD1'/></div>";
echo "  <div class='reglbl'>Confirm Password: <input type='password' name='PWD2' id='PWD2'/></div>";
echo "  <div><input type='submit' name='formSubmit'value='Register' id='sub' /></div>";
echo "</form>";
if(isset($_REQUEST['formSubmit']) && $_REQUEST['formSubmit'] == 'Register')
{
if(!isset($_REQUEST['FirstName']) ||
    !isset($_REQUEST['LastName']) ||
    !isset($_REQUEST['email']) ||
    !isset($_REQUEST['PhoneNum']) ||
    !isset($_REQUEST['PWD1']) ||
    !isset($_REQUEST['PWD2']) ||
    $_REQUEST['FirstName'] =="" ||
    $_REQUEST['LastName'] == "" ||
    $_REQUEST['email'] == "" ||
    $_REQUEST['PhoneNum'] == "" ||
    $_REQUEST['PWD1'] == "" ||
    $_REQUEST['PWD2']=="") 
{
    echo "<script>alert('Please enter all fields!')</script>";
} elseif($_REQUEST['PWD1']!=$_REQUEST['PWD2']) {
    echo "<script>alert('Passwords entered do not match!')</script>";
} elseif(strlen($_REQUEST['PWD1'])<8||strlen($_REQUEST['PWD2'])<8) {
    echo "<script>alert('Passwords must be 8 or more characters!')</script>";
} else {
    // CALL A FUNCTION IN PHP HERE
}
}
?>
```

javascript function you can add more validation for the length of password

```
<script>
function regValidation(){

var firstName = document.getElementById('FirstNameID');
var lastName = document.getElementById('LastNameID');
var email = document.getElementById('EmailID');
var pwd1 = document.getElementById('PWD1');
var pwd2 = document.getElementById('PWD2');


if(firstName.value == '' || lastName.value == '' || email.value == '' || pwd1.value == '' || pwd2.value == '')
{
    alert("Please enter all fields!");
}
else if (pwd1.value !== pwd2.value)
{
    alert("Passwords entered do not match!");   
}
else
{
    return true;
}
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: ive tired the changes with the  If statement and the returns but it still does not work. It only checks js validation.